# Bundle Data not receiving in Activity from GCM

Tags: android

I am trying to send some data in extras from gcm service to my activity, but the bundle is coming null.
I have tried using Bundle extra and intent extras method and tried to receive them onCreate and in onNewIntent method. 
For some reason, it is not being received.

**Here is my code in my GcmService :-**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
        bundle.putString(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, fromId);
        bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, MessageThreadDao.TYPE_HOST);

        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, fromId);
        intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, MessageThreadDao.TYPE_HOST);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String soundPref = Utility.getStringSharedPreference(this, AppConstants.PREFS_SOUND);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher)).setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.rental_notification)).setContentText(msg);

        if (soundPref.equals("1"))
            mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        else {
            mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(""));
        }

        //        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        //            mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.header_blue));
        //        }
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

**Here is my code in my Activity :-**

```
//In onCreate
        mReservationId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
            mHostOrConciergerId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, 0);
            mHostType = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, 0);

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        try {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

            mReservationId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
            mHostOrConciergerId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, 0);
            mHostType = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, 0);
        }
        retrieveChatHistoryFromDB();

    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

in Android Manifest :-

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.ChatActivity"
            android:label="@string/messages"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

I am not setting any flags also. Just a simple intent, still data is not being received.

Comment: you mean `onNewIntent` will be invoked,but extra data is null?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this code from GCM service class

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
        bundle.putString(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, fromId);
        bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, MessageThreadDao.TYPE_HOST);

 intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Comment: I just put it their because i tried both ways - by putting data via intent and via bundle

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the launch mode of your activity manifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: I don't want singleTop.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from the code

```
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, fromId);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, MessageThreadDao.TYPE_HOST);
```

It should be like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_RESERVATION_ID, 0);
bundle.putString(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_OR_CONCIERGE_ID, fromId);
bundle.putInt(AppConstants.KEY_HOST_TYPE, MessageThreadDao.TYPE_HOST);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

The Activity you want to receive onNewIntent() should have

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Or add the flag t0 intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: What if i don't want singleTop ? I dont want any flags. Data should still come right ?. I have this activity opened and i want to open a new instance of this activity.

Comment: It is coming in onCreate() only, but the bundle is coming null

Comment: let u try the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP flag in your intent. if its not work try with both flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP. There is no any other way to do this. if you find any solution for this please share your solution, so that other can learn from it.